# Find n $\in \mathbb{N}^*$so that the equality is true for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

I recently came across this problem...and it surpassed my understanding of maths. It goes as follows:

Find the n nonzero natural number, such that it satisfies the expression:

$$[(x+y)^n-(x^n+y^n)]^2=n^2x^2y^2(x+y)^2(x^2+xy+y^2)^{n-3}$$

where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

I noticed we could do something with the $x^2+xy+y^2$ term, so I tried to turn that term into a cube:

$$(x^2+xy+y^2)^{n-3}=\frac{(x-y)^{n-3}(x^2+xy+y^2)^{n-3}}{(x-y)^{n-3}}=\frac{(x^3-y^3)^{n-3}}{(x-y)^{n-3}}$$

And this is the point where I can't go on with simplifying terms. I might try squaring the LHS, but it wouldn't lead me nowhere in my opinion.

Comment: Setting $(x,y)$ to $(1,1)$ gives three values for $n$.  Then it's a matter of testing each.

Comment: Hmm...but wouldn't those 3 n's be the only solutions? If it is true for all x and y then no matter what we choose, we would only get those 3 n's, rigth?

Comment: Not following.  The general $n$ must work for $(1,1)$, of course.  But the fact that $n$ works for one point doesn't mean it holds generally.  Therefore, the solution (if it exists) has to be one of those three values, but presumably the other two values fail. Still, checking for a particular $n$ shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Note:  checking the three candidates at some other point, like $(2,1)$ or whatever, ought to eliminate the bad values (if there are any) quickly.  Then you only have to work with one candidate.

Comment: Now it's clear...thank you very much!

Comment: By the way...wouldn't other $(x,y)$ values give other n's which would need to be taken into consideration as well?

Comment: I don't understand.  The method I proposed was a quick way to determine the possible $n$.  It doesn't solve the problem completely.  Given one of  the three values my method leaves, you need to verify that the identity holds for all $(x,y)$ using that value.  The point, of course, is that it's much, much easier to check an identity for a known $n$ then it is to try to solve the whole thing algebraically.

Comment: I know and sorry for any misunderstanding...what I meant to say could it happen that I choose such x and y that I get a different n from those that I get from the (1,1) scenario (I know the solutions are going to be 3,5 and 7, even though I can't really solve the equation)? Or the (1,1) scenario provides us the 3 potential solutions out of which 2 are   not solutions to the original equation?

Comment: I think you still aren't getting it.  The $(1,1)$ case gives you three candidates, $3,5,7$ as you say.  You need to test the identity for each of those.  A priori, all of them might work, none of them might work, some might work.  But in each case you have a clear algebraic equality which you can prove or disprove.

Comment: I got it. Only my formulation might be a little bit intricate. Sorry for that. One question though...how to solve the equation I got from the (1,1) case? Or in general...how to tackle such equations?

Comment: I just did the $(1,1)$ case graphically.  The left hand dominates quickly so you only need to look at small values.  In general, high power equations can be extremely difficult.

Comment: Okay...I will try my best...thank you once again!